# How to download .xls header PHP file fom PHP with cURL

Tags: php, excel, curl

So, I have a PHP script (script 1) that is a basic web page that I echo some text to the user. Whenever the user loads script 1, I want to POST to a PHP script that is has these headers :

```
header("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=EXCBOSSTesting.xls"); 
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
```

I am using cURL to call the script but it isn't downloading the file like I want it to. Keep in mind the .xls file is **generated once it is called, it doesn't exist as a static file on the server**. Here is my code at the moment.

```
$url = "http://mywebsite.com/script2.php";

$fields = array(
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'user' => 'currUser'
);

$postVars = http_build_query($fields);

//open the connection
$ch = curl_init();

$user = 'example';
$pass = 'examplePass';

$headers = array("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user . ":" . $pass);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);

curl_exec($ch);

// close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

If I go the script2's URL in my browser, it will download the .xls file and it works just fine. What am I missing here?

Comment: How did you come up with this convoluted workaround? See also: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- `curl_exec()` doesn't output anything by itself. It wouldn't replay response headers in particular. Also feeding the faux Excel MIME type as request `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` won't do anything useful.

Comment: @mario, I didn't come up with any workaround. Should i have $result = curl_exec($ch); echo $result; instead?

Comment: @mario, should I get rid of the 'Content Type' header then? Should I replace it with something else?

Comment: Or you should have fixed your orginal script to not depend on POST fields?

Comment: @mario, I could do that, but since the original script exports the result of a mysql query that needs a username, date, and other variables I thought that it would be best to use POST. Is there a better solution?